# How to Capture Request and Response in testSuite TearDown using groovy

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have a testSuite with lets say 5 cases, i run the cases from my testSuite.

In my tear down script I want to capture all request and response of all testcases all test testSteps.

Below is the code I have written in tearDown TestSuite, problem in context.expand is returning empty. I assume testCase context is require, or not sure where i am going wrong.

```
tc_list = testSuite.getTestCaseList()
tc_count = tc_list.size()
for(i=0;i<tc_list.size();i++){
    if(!tc_list[i].isDisabled()){

        ts_list =  tc_list[i].getTestStepList()

        for(j=0;j<ts_list.size();j++){
            req = testSuite.getPropertyValue("reportpath")+'/'+testSuite.getName()+'/'+tc_list[i].getName()+'/'+ts_list[j].getName()+'_RequestData.txt'
            res = testSuite.getPropertyValue("reportpath")+'/'+testSuite.getName()+'/'+tc_list[i].getName()+'/'+ts_list[j].getName()+'_ResponseData.txt'

            def request_expand = context.expand('${'+ts_list[j].getName()+'#Request}')
            log.info '${'+ts_list[j].getName()+'#Response}'+tc_list[i].getName()
               def response_expand = context.expand('${'+ts_list[j].getName()+'#Response}')
              log.info response_expand



             /* def req_file = new File(req)
               req_file.write(request_expand,"UTF-8")
               def res_file = new File(res)
               res_file.write(response_expand,"UTF-8") */



            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: Are you using open source edition? or Pro? Usually it captures request and response for the failed steps. Do you those irrespective of the result status?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Ragesh kr

Whenever any time in Soap ui or Ready API you need **RawRequest** or **RawResponse**

you can just replace Request with  **Raw**Request
                 and Response with **Raw**Response

i just did in your code and it worked

```
        def request_expand = testSuite.getTestCaseByName(tc_list[i].getName()).getTestStepByName(ts_list[j].getName()).getPropertyValue("RawRequest")
        def response_expand = testSuite.getTestCaseByName(tc_list[i].getName()).getTestStepByName(ts_list[j].getName()).getPropertyValue("RawResponse")
```

Some other examples to help everyone

When we just need request and response in soapui we can use below

[image]

When we just need RawRequest and RawResponse in soapui/ReadyaPI via groovy we can use below

```
 req=context.expand('${RequestStepName#RawRequest}')
 log.info req
 res=context.expand('${RequestStepName#RawResponse}')
 log.info res
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Below code worked for me. But I am still trying to capture rawRequest and rawResponse, which is still not achieved

```
tc_list = testSuite.getTestCaseList()
tc_count = tc_list.size()
for(i=0;i<tc_list.size();i++){
    if(!tc_list[i].isDisabled()){

        ts_list =  tc_list[i].getTestStepList()

        for(j=0;j<ts_list.size();j++){

            req = testSuite.getPropertyValue("reportpath")+'/'+testSuite.getName()+'/'+tc_list[i].getName()+'/'+ts_list[j].getName()+'_RequestData.txt'
            res = testSuite.getPropertyValue("reportpath")+'/'+testSuite.getName()+'/'+tc_list[i].getName()+'/'+ts_list[j].getName()+'_ResponseData.txt'

            def request_expand = testSuite.getTestCaseByName(tc_list[i].getName()).getTestStepByName(ts_list[j].getName()).getPropertyValue("Request")
            def response_expand = testSuite.getTestCaseByName(tc_list[i].getName()).getTestStepByName(ts_list[j].getName()).getPropertyValue("Response")
            def req_file = new File(req)
            def res_file = new File(res)
            log.info testSuite.getTestCaseByName(tc_list[i].getName()).getName()+' '+testSuite.getTestCaseByName(tc_list[i].getName()).getTestStepByName(ts_list[j].getName()).getName()+' '+response_expand
            if(request_expand!=null && response_expand!=null){

                 log.info testSuite.getTestCaseByName(tc_list[i].getName()).getName()+' '+testSuite.getTestCaseByName(tc_list[i].getName()).getTestStepByName(ts_list[j].getName()).getName()+' '+response_expand

               req_file.write(request_expand,"UTF-8")

               res_file.write(response_expand,"UTF-8")
                }

            }
        }


    }
```